# ¿Como hacer para que el enlace disminuya?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

El hover para dar click en el enlace es de todo el contenedor del navegador, pero yo quiero que solo se pueda dar click en las letras, no en todo el contenedor.
¿Como se puede solucionar esto?
o sea, reducir el area para dar click en los enlaces

### Muchas gracias!

El hover para dar click en el enlace es de todo el contenedor del navegador, pero yo quiero que solo se pueda dar click en las letras, no en todo el contenedor.
¿Como se puede solucionar esto?
o sea, reducir el area para dar click en los enlaces
Muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tal Jorge. podrias escribir el codigo de css y html, para poder ayudarte, solo con la imagen es dificil ver porque esta pasando esto. Gracias

Comment: Listo ya agregue el codigo

Comment: ¿Y donde está el código?

Comment: el problema será de css,los enlaces por defecto no tienen ese comportamiento pero deberías poner el HTML y el CSS y hacerlo con texto, no con una imagen. Mira aquí porque no debes usar imágenes para el código: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2869#2869

Comment: @Jorge por favor ayudanos, escribiendo el codigo que tienes actualmente, pueden ser diferentes cosas que puedan causar este comportamiento, solo con lo que nos dices no te podemos ayudar.
Un [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) o [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) es util. Tambien te sugiero que sigas las recomendaciones para crear un [ejemplo minimo repoducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Gracias!!

Comment: Perdonen, no se subio el codigo, pero aqui esta https://jsfiddle.net/1ydh23vx/. Me dijeron que si ponia toda la etiqueta entre un "span" arreglaria el problema, y si <span class="verde"> <a href="#" > Raspados </a> </span> si lo pongo asi se arregla, pero quisiera saber porque, de todos modos el codigo de ahi no esta arreglado. Aprecio mucho su ayuda!

Comment: En el ejemplo que has puesto no ocurre lo mismo que en la imagen

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que tienes `display:flex` en `navegacion-principal` y por defecto la propiedad `align-items` toma el valor `stretch` que hace que los hijos crezcan hasta ocupar toda la altura del padre. Si cambias ese valor se corregirá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El elemento `a` es un [elemento en-linea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elementos_en_l%C3%ADnea) por defecto, lo que significa que solo ocupa el espacio de su contenido.

En este caso `a` se esta comportando como un [elemento de bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)
puede usar cualquiera de las siguientes soluciones

- Cambiar la regla display de `.navegacion-principal`

```
    .navegacion-principal {
      display: block; // valor por defecto (lo mismo que no tener regla 'display')
      ...
    }
```

- envolver con otro elemento cada elemento `a`

```
    <nav class="navegacion-principal">
       <div>
          <a href="#" class="verde"> Raspados </a>
       </div>
       <div>
          <a href="#" class="verde"> Tejuino</a>
       </div>
       .
       .
       .
    </nav>
```

Lo que sucede con tu codigo es que estas modificando las propiedades por defecto de tus elementos `a`.

considerando el siguiente codigo extraido de tu ejemplo:

```
.navegacion-principal {
  /* min-width: 80vw; */
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}
```

`.navegacion-principal` es el padre directo de todos tus elementos `a` los cuales son modificados por medio de la regla `display: flex;` definida en el codigo anterior.

Cuando agregas un `span`, u otro elemento como un `div` para contener el elemento `a` este ya no es afectado, debido a que `.navigation-principal` ya no es su padre directo.

Te recomiendo leer mas sobre [elementos en linea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elementos_en_l%C3%ADnea), [elementos de bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), asi como [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Flexbox). Conocer las diferencias entre estos, es fundamental para dominar CSS.

Comment: Gracias! ya habia podido arreglarlo, el problema fue que me confundi con el Flex y lo agregue, como usted dice, en la clase de todos los "nav". Muchas gracias por ayudar! <3

Answer (score 2):

Puedes cambiar los el orden de los elementos.

Imagino tienes el estilo ubicado sobre las etiquetas **a** algo asi:

```
.navegacion-principal a{
  #codigo..
}
```

Intenta cambiándolo hacia una etiqueta **span**

```
.navegacion-principal span{
   #codigo..
}
```

y luego tu html quedaria

```
<nav class="navegacion-principal">
   <span class="verde">
      <a href="#" > Raspados </a>
   </span>
   <span class="verde">
      <a href="#" > Tejuino</a>
   </span>
   .
   .
   .
</nav>
```

Comment: Pero si agrego la etiqueta Span, para seleccionar, si se acomoda el area para dar click, pero ahora no toma los valores que le pongo a el selector navegacion-principal span {}, le puse un color y nada :c, ademas, ¿podrias explicarme a que se debe que entre las etiquetas "span" se corrige el area? Gracias!